# How to disable javascript file caching in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I have a file under app/assets/javascripts/templates.js.erb which loads templates from other html views.

```
= javascript_include_tag "templates.js"
```

In development mode, my templates are changing very often so templates.js.erb should be re-processed at every page load. But it is cached **unless the code in the file** changes.

How can I force rails to re-execute templates.js.erb at every page request in development mode?

Comment: you can use `<script>` tag in layout or particular views for reloading it Thanks

Comment: good catch! so right know I'm using:
`
    - if Rails.env.development?
      - file_path = Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "javascripts", "templates.js.erb")
      script= ERB.new(File.new(file_path).read).result.html_safe
    - else
      = javascript_include_tag "templates.js"
`

Comment: can I make it post to vote me up?..thanks

Comment: hi Vincentp can you please vote me up on my post ..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use your js code inside `<script>` tag in layout or particular views for reloading it

Thanks –

Answer (score 0):

you can check in controller wether the request is ajax or not by checking request.xhr? so you 
can chached your action conditionally

for example
  caches_page :show, :if => lambda { !request.xhr? }